# ASP.NET/VB date works on localhost but not remoteserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I'm having alot of trouble trying to get the date from a DateTime picker to save to my database. It works fine when run from Localhost, but when running it on the public server it doesn't. 
Originally i used the cDate function, plus also tried Convert.ToDateTime. But on the server it now gives me an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I researched and found that its best to used the DateTime.TryParse function. After finding an example i changed it for my project and now im getting the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@articledate"."

When i debug the project, the value added into the "result1" DateTime is correct. But it still throws the error at ExecuteNonQuery?

If it makes a difference, the main server is hosted with GoDaddy, Localhost is my PC.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    cnSQL1 = New SqlConnection(MSSQL.cRemoteConnectionString)
    cnSQL1.Open()
    sSQL = "SELECT NewsID FROM News WHERE Season = @season AND Heading = @heading AND ArticleDate = @articledate AND Author = @author AND Club = @club AND State = @state AND AddedDate = @addeddate AND AddedBy = @addedby AND Release = @release"
    Dim com1 As New SqlCommand(sSQL)
    com1.Connection = cnSQL1
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@season", General.sSeason)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heading", General.UppercaseFirstLetter(txtHeading.Text))
    Dim result1 As DateTime
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articledate", DateTime.TryParseExact(txtArticleDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result1))
    'com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articledate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtArticleDate.Text))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtAuthor.Text)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", ddlClub.SelectedItem.Value)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", dsState.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addeddate", Date.Today)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addedby", Session("UserID"))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updatedate", Date.Today)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateby", Session("UserID"))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@release", s)
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: When you set up the datepicker, dictate that the format is a safe, non-ambiguous format that is not influenced by regional or language settings. `yyyymmdd` is safe (`yyyy-mm-dd` is not, nor are `m/d/y` or `d/m/y`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *"Must declare the scalar variable "@articledate"* is caused by a typo. When you add the parameter you should use the SqlCommand variable named *com1* not the variable *com*.

But after this you have a more critical error. All the [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) methods return booleans. The converted date is written in the last parameter passed to TryParse.

In this way you are passing a boolean to `AddWithValue` and this method takes whatever you put in the value parameter. It has no way to know that you want a date, so it happily complies with your request.

You should do (Notice that the SqlCommand to use is `com1` not `com`)

```
Dim result1 As DateTime
if DateTime.TryParseExact(txtArticleDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result1) Then
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articledate", resul1)
Else
    .....
```

In general it is better to [avoid AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) exactly because it takes whatever you pass to it. The preferred way is with

```
if DateTime.TryParseExact(txtArticleDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result1) Then
    com1.Parameters.Add("@articledate", SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = result1
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@season", General.sSeason)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heading", General.UppercaseFirstLetter(txtHeading.Text))

    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtAuthor.Text)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", ddlClub.SelectedItem.Value)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", dsState.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addeddate", Date.Today)
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addedby", Session("UserID"))
    ' This is not used by the query, commented out
    ' com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updatedate", Date.Today)
    ' This is not used by the query, commented out
    ' com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateby", Session("UserID"))
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@release", s)
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Date is not valid")
End If
```

I have also removed two parameters that are not used in the query above (though they should not cause the error message above)

Comment: thanks for the tip with Adding Parameters. I'm still having issues with the date unfortunately. When it gets to the If Statement, it returns false. so skips over the adding of the Parameter and throws the Scalar exception. Does the "result1" get set when declared or when the If Statement is run? I have copied the above code (second answer) into my project but still throws the error

Comment: What is the exact error message now? Consider that I have put a if to check if the input date is correct or not. If it isn't correct then you shouldn't execute the query. I will expand the second example to better explain the flow

Comment: When Debugging, 'If DateTime.TryParseExact(txtArticleDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result1) Then' will return False.
So when it comes to Execute the query it shows the same as above 'Must declare the scalar variable "@articledate"'

If it helps. txtArticledate,text shows "28/01/2017" and result1 shows "#12:00:00 AM#"

Comment: Change the format mask to _dd/MM/yyyy_ and use your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (but probably it should work also with InvariantCulture if  you specify the correct date separator) or better follow the sound advice from Aaron Bertrand about using a DateTimePicker correctly formatted, instead of a TextBox. You don't need anymore the parsing code

Comment: I took the advice and did away with the textbox and just used the DateTimePicker. Not as nice as i was hoping for but it does the job without over complicating it. Thank you for all the help!